# Can the long range scope be found at non-military locations?

Tags: dayz-standalone

I know that the long range scope for the mosin is quite rare and is very likely to be found at military locations (baracks, tents, police departments, ACTs).
However I dislike going to these locations alone as I consider them to be dangerous and they are often looted anyway.

Can I find the long range scope at other locations and where?

Comment: Up untill now I've only found them on Military bases. Mostly in tents and hangars. You can always go for a low population server in the hopes of finding it while being a little safer.

Answer (score 1):

I probably shouldn't be telling you this but here it goes. I find the best place to look is Zelenogorsk. It has military, lots of civ and also lots of storage lockers. Some people do go there but it seems to be much less popular than other places for some reason, maybe because it is on the other side of the map where people are spawning right now. I have found the long range scope in a storage locker one time. other times they have been in jails or barracks. It seems as though they got even more rare two patches ago.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to the [map](http://dayzdb.com/map/chernarusplus#4.085.083;item=Long%20Range%20Scope). But it is one of the rarest item in the game, so you should be very lucky to find it on non-military locations.

Comment: I wouldn't trust the map, most (if not all) of the loot data is pulled from the mod afaik.

Comment: I have found it in a house in Balota. Military stuff like scopes can be found in house. The probability for this kind of object to spawn in residential area is something like 0.001. Better than 0

Comment: I've found flashlights, bipods in Svtloyarsk too. So this stuff isn't rare, but Long Ranged scope is rarest thing of them.

Answer (score 0):

There is a prison at green mountain and a prison NW of NWAF about 1000m away, in the middle of a forest. Very few players know about these locations so I suggest going there, also these places can't be sniped from but can still be camped, so I suggest going on a low population server if you are still paranoid.